# AIX grep regular expression

Tags: bash, grep, aix

I need to extract information from a file that contains datetime stamp as below

`[01/Sep/2023:08:10:45 +0200]`

I want to match all lines for year 2023 using grep on AIX

I tried `grep -E "\[.*(\/2023)*\]"` but didn't work.

Okay - I wasn't clear enough it looks like.. Here's a sample data from the actual file

```
10.239.45.25 - - [01/Sep/2022:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.218.72.116 - - [01/Sep/2022:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.66.244.120 - - [01/Sep/2022:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.239.45.25 - - [01/Sep/2022:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.218.72.116 - - [01/Sep/2023:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.66.244.120 - - [01/Sep/2023:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
```

I am expecting the output to be only the last 2 lines since they are in year 2023 regardless of anything else like below

```
10.218.72.116 - - [01/Sep/2023:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.66.244.120 - - [01/Sep/2023:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
```

Comment: Use `grep '\[[^]]*2023[^]]*]' file`

Comment: With your shown samples please try following regex `^\[\d+\/[a-zA-Z]{3}\/2023:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s+\+[0-9]{4}\]$` Here is a working demo: https://regex101.com/r/OpR5R5/1

Comment: Why not simply `grep '\[../.../2023'` ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The regex you tried `grep -E "\[.*(\/2023)*\]"` is missing a `.` after the close parentheses. It should be `grep -E "\[.*(\/2023).*\]"`

Comment: Not my downvote, but you probably want to sharpen the regex some more than that. This minimal fix corrects the immediate problem, but will produce false matches where the 2023 occurs outside the closing square bracket if there is another closing square bracket somewhere later on the line. A better fix might be `grep '^\[[^][]*/2023[^][]*\]`

Answer (score 6):

In general don't try to match numbers with regexps, do numeric comparisons, e.g. using any awk:

```
$ awk -F'[/:]' '$3 == 2023' file
10.218.72.116 - - [01/Sep/2023:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.66.244.120 - - [01/Sep/2023:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
```

and then you can trivially adapt it to print lines before or after that year by just changing `==` to `<` or `>`, etc, e.g.:

```
$ awk -F'[/:]' '$3 < 2023' file
10.239.45.25 - - [01/Sep/2022:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.218.72.116 - - [01/Sep/2022:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.66.244.120 - - [01/Sep/2022:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.239.45.25 - - [01/Sep/2022:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
```

Answer (score 2):

If depends very much on the input but for your example and any other lines having the same format, this would do

```
grep '/2023:' file
```

resulting in

```
10.218.72.116 - - [01/Sep/2023:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.66.244.120 - - [01/Sep/2023:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
```

Answer (score 0):

side note : if you wanna just extract out the year-number and nothing else, try this hands-free approach :

```
echo '

10.239.45.25 - - [01/Sep/2022:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.218.72.116 - - [01/Sep/2022:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.66.244.120 - - [01/Sep/2022:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.239.45.25 - - [01/Sep/2022:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.218.72.116 - - [01/Sep/2023:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279
10.66.244.120 - - [01/Sep/2023:08:10:45 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 279' |
```

> ```
> {m,g,n}awk ++NF FS='[^:]+/|:.+$' OFS=
> ```

```
2022
2022
2022
2022
2023
2023
```

Answer (score 0):

That pretty much did what I needed

```
grep -E ".*\[[^][]*\/2023[^][]*\].*" file
```

Thanks @Verpous

Comment: The two `.*`s and the backslashes before `/` and `]` in your regexp are doing nothing useful, you could just remove them. That regexp is open to failing with false matches depending on your input though, you have much better answers.